# Mercurial : Combine Revisions 1 and 4 only

Tags: merge, mercurial

say i have a local clone called `test` that i am working on. test has 5 changesets as follows (4 being the latest changeset):

```
Test:
0 -- 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4
```

Q1. How can i merge / collapse / combine changeset 4 with changeset 1 (I do not want the diff of 2 and 3 included) so it looks like this (3 being the merged 1 and 4)

```
Test:
0 -- 1 -- 2 -- 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Without MQ: [Histedit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) extension
2. Using MQ extension: [Editing History](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory)

Additional reading: [Concatenating Changesets](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConcatenatingChangesets), [Collapse Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension)

PS: I'll prefer to use pure MQ-way